# Android SDK r18 appears to have broken ORMLite

Tags: java, android, sdk, ormlite

I am using ormlite v4.35 and I just had to update my android tools to r18 in eclipse, because the IDE would not build my project until I upgraded the tools. After the upgrade the following line throws an error:

```
mDbHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
```

The exception is a `NoClassDefFoundError`

I went to the ormlite website and saw there was a newer version (4.40) downloaded and replaced the reference with the newer version, unfortunately that did not fix the problem. Has anyone run into the issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 10):

> The exception is a NoClassDefFoundError

I think your problem is around the new behavior of the `libs` folder with [Android r17 tools](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects).  You *must* have your [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) jars in the `libs` folder.  This is just the `-android` and `-core` class jars -- not the javadoc or source jars which I just put at the root of the project.

Once you move the jars there, the Android builders should see your classes.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, one week before release on a 2 month project and this happen, you are a life saver!

Comment: user1356306 then you should vote his answer up and/or accept it ;-)

Comment: He's a new user and he can't vote up @ligi.  Also, he has to wait 30 minutes or something before he can accept it.  :-)

Comment: It drives nuts. 4 hours fighting checking and rewriting classes.